# Decrypting PDF files with Excel attachments in Python

Tags: python, pdf

I tried using PyPDF2 to unencrypt and then send off attachments of PDF files landing in my inbox but realised this is not going to work because those PDFs have attachments in them (excel) and can only be accessed if decrpyted via Adobe Reader.

Is there API or a simple way of using Adobe Reader api via Python to decrypt these PDF files and retain those excel files?

I've tried Chatgpt and google but there's no documentation on this.